# How do I use a switch on Xcode viewcontroller?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have read a book on Swift logic but I don't know how to use it with an interface to make an app in xCode 8. I'm making a very basic app where you have a currency (coins) and when you click a button (goldPan) it checks to see what upgrade the goldPan is on and depending on that upgrade the user gets so many coins, basically like the game cookie clicker. Instead of writing a ton of "if" statements I decided I have built a "switch" to check what upgrade the goldPan is on. Also, the goldPan has its own class. Im more of asking the question of "is Switch the way to go to check the upgrade? and if so how do I implement it with my code. Like I said, Im not sure if it's the most efficient way but when I do use this, Im getting the error of

> Use of instance member 'checkUpgradeNumber' on type 'ViewController.goldPan'; did you mean to use a value of type 'ViewController.goldPan' instead?

and

> Instance member 'production' cannot be used on type 'ViewController.goldPan'

Please help me, Im not sure if the switch is the best way to go or something else. Sorry for the very noob question. My code is below:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var topLabel: UILabel!

var coins = 0;

class goldPan {

    var upgradeNumber = 0

    var production = 1

    func checkUpgradeNumber() {


    switch upgradeNumber {
    case 0:
        production = 1;
    case 1:
        production = 2;
    case 2:
        production = 3;
    default:
        production = 1;
    }

    }


}

@IBAction func goldPanButton(_ sender: Any) {
goldPan.checkUpgradeNumber();
coins = coins + goldPan.production
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `class goldPan` to `func goldPan`

I don't think you can have a class within a class. This may not fix the whole problem, but it might fix part of it. I'm not completely sure on this, but I just noticed that you are using a class instead of a function.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please consider the naming convention that class names start with capital letter (`GoldPan`).

You are calling a method and accessing a property on the class which is not possible with that code.

Either make the method and the properties **static**

```
...
static var upgradeNumber = 0
static  var production = 1

class func checkUpgradeNumber() { ...
```

or create an **instance** of the class

```
let goldPan = Goldpan()
goldPan.checkUpgradeNumber()
coins = coins + goldPan.production
```

But basically I suppose you don't need to use a separate class for that. Remove the inner `class` block and use the method and the properties in the `ViewController` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

```
switch upgradeNumber {
case 0:
    production = 1;
case 1:
    production = 2;
case 2:
    production = 3;
default:
    production = 1;
}
```

With:

```
production = upgradeNumber + 1
```

Comment: i_am_jorf's answer covers most cases but if upgradeNumber is greater than 3 it won't produce the same result.    For example if upgradeNumber is 3 then the switch statement would make production=1 but the proposed method would make production=4.     So it depends what you want for higher numbers.  If you did want to produce the same result with a simplified switch you could us:
`switch upgradeNumber {
case 0...2:
    production = upgradeNumber + 1
default:
    production = 1;
}`